# How to get data from a web-page using Selenium in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I need to extract some info using Selenium from a page, these elements are not on the page's code(seemingly it's JavaScript).
That's what I'm doing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

path = '...'
URL = '...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path) # successfully connecting to 
                                                # Chrome
driver.get(URL)                                 # following the link
```

*NB*

It's an example of elements I need:

```
<span class="wrapper__top_3ztMC">
      Машинное зрение DA
</span>
```

And I've got some questions here.

**Question #1.**
Why don't these work:

1)

```
result = driver.find_element_by_class_name('wrapper__top_3ztMC')
```

2. 

```
result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='wrapper__top_3ztMC']")
```

3. 

```
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="wrapper__top_3ztMC"]')
```

The same error in 3 cases:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='wrapper__top_3ztMC']"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

**Question #2.**
Why doesn't this work:

```
result = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper__top_3ztMC')")
result
```

Returns an empty list [].

**BUT!**

This:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "wrapper__top_3ztMC"))
    )
```

returns the 1st element (because I'm using 'until').
Eventually: it looks like the first 3 ways don't work because the data needs some time to display on the page and the page itself has to load a bit longer than the code works.

**The main question.**

How do I make it so that not the first element is output, but absolutely all those whose class meets the specified one? By the way, another problem is that the page is long, and in order for the other elements to be displayed as well, you need to scroll to the end - this also needs to be taken into account.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the URL is public if yes please share.

Comment: but you have to authorize beforehand: https://ai.leader-id.ru/contest/1/stage/1/activity/4/

Comment: Have a hunch the suffix `_3ztMC` is changing each time

Comment: No, it's always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for your `HTML` code

```
<span class="wrapper__top_3ztMC">
      Машинное зрение DA
</span>
```

you need to get the parent element of the `span` in order to display the text of the `span`

Let's say, for example, that the parent of your `span` is a `div`. So, in order to get the text of the `span`, you would need to use the following `xpath`

```
# xpath to locate span's parent element
//div//span[contains(., 'wrapper__top_3ztMC')]/..

# use xpath to get the text of the span
myText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div//span[contains(., 'wrapper__top_3ztMC')]/..").text
print(f'Span Text is: {myText}')
```

What this `xpath` does is locate the `span` element in your browser's `DOM` and then traverses / moves up 1 level to the parent node. Going to the parent node of the `span` will allow you to access the text inside of the `span`. If your `span` is a button, then you can use the `xpath` to click on the element also.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div//span[contains(., 'wrapper__top_3ztMC')]/..").click()
```

The main key is in

```
//span[contains(., 'wrapper__top_3ztMC')]
```

The `contains(., 'Whatever')` tells `selenium` to search for the `HTML` node for anything that contains your "wrapper__top_3ztMC" text. This is a way to be able to find `span` elements. But, in order to interact with the `span` element, you need to go to the parent node by using the `/..` at the end of your `xpath`.

**Scroll To Element Answer**

Once you find your element by using `xpath`

```
//div//span[contains(., 'wrapper__top_3ztMC')]/..
```

you can scroll to the element by using `JavaScript`

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div//span[contains(., 'wrapper__top_3ztMC')]/..")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: @amateur - Can you add a photo of the `HTML` code so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: @amateur - Also, you can remove the `//div` that was just written for explanation purposes. Also, open your browser's Developer Tools ( F12 if you are using Chrome ) and do `CTRL + F` in the Elements Tab and paste in the `xpath` `//span[contains(., 'wrapper__top_3ztMC')` to see how many elements display for yourself. If it is more than 1, then you need to specify which index you want.  `//span[contains(., 'wrapper__top_3ztMC')[1]`

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for your help) But as it turned out the issue was in the IDE I used, the code was correct from the concept of logic.

Comment: @amateur - Oh! Well, I'm glad!

Answer (score 0):

"How do I make it so that not the first element is output, but absolutely all those whose class meets the specified one?" For this question, the answer is you can use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath`.

To scroll until the end of the page, you can use this code:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: The page is designed so that it has a certain Height but when I scroll till the bottom it automatically expands and so on. So when the script is loaded it takes the initial Height and then stops. I need to go farther.